# Navigation menu does not respond correctly when adjusting screen size

Tags: html, css, navigation, media-queries, response

This a question that i am still working on from a previous question I posted but haven't resolved it and feel i need to be more clear.

I have a basic responsive nav bar that does not re display the main navigation after the following process has been carried out.

1)  Shrink the navigation and open the responsive nav

2) Close the responsive nav using the button.

3)  reopen the browser to full width.

4) the Original Nav links are still hidden. ! i cant get them to show back unless you refresh the screen.

Here is my fiddle.

Id you can help, please update the fiddle.

Thanks 
http://jsfiddle.net/d6Cc8/3/

```
body{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  background: url(../img/assets/body-bg.gif) repeat;
}
  #wrap{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #wrap-inner{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top:80px;
  }
    #wrap-inner-profile{
      padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  #content{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: url(../img/assets/body-bg.gif) repeat;
  }
  #content .center{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .general-container{
    max-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px;
  }
li{
  list-style: none;
}
a:link, a:visited{
  color: #4083a9;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}
a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #205f82;
}
ul, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, p{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;;
}
p{
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}
img:hover{
  opacity: .7;
}
    #header{
      width: 100%;
      height: 53px;
      background: #333;
      background: rgba(47,47,47,0.98);
      z-index: 9999;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
    }
      #header-inner{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0 12px;
        max-width: 970px;
      }
      #header-icons{
        position: absolute;
        top: 18px;
        right: 95px;
      }
        #logo{
          float: left;
          padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
        }
            #logo a{
              display: block;
              width: 107px;
              height: 50px;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: 0 50%;
              background-image: url(../img/assets/chartego-logo.png);
              -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
              -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
              -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
              transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
              }

             #logo img{
              height: 0;
             }

              #logo a:hover{
               opacity: .6;
             }
              #upload-btn{
                background: #86c343;
                margin-top: 12px;
                padding: 7px 12px 8px 12px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
                -moz-border-radius: 4px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                margin-right: 30px;
              }
               #upload-btn a{
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 11px;
               }
               #upload-btn:hover{
                background: #79b33a;
               }
               #upload-green-btn{
                display: block;
               }
               #upload-responsive{
                display: none !important;
               }
               .main-btn{
                  display: block;
                  text-align: center;
                  font: normal 1.6em "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, sans-serif;
                  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                  border-radius: 6px;
                  border: none !important;
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  color: #fff !important;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  font-size: 16px;
                  background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #bdbdbd;
               }
               .main-btn:hover{
                  background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #a1a1a1;
               }
                a.main-btn{
                  color: white;
                  }

               input.main-btn{
                  display: block;
                  font: normal 1.6em "Helvetica Neue", helvetica, sans-serif;
                  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                  border-radius: 6px;
                  border: none !important;
                  padding: 10px 20px;
                  color: #fff !important;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  font-size: 16px;
               }
               input.main-btn:hover{
                  background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #a1a1a1;
               }
                .main-btn.orange{
                   background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #ff6a00;
                   display: block;
                   text-align: center;
                }
                 .main-btn.orange:hover{
                   background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #ff8025;
                }
                 .main-btn.green{
                    background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #4eaa32;
                    display: block;
                   text-align: center;
                }
                .main-btn.green:hover{
                      background: url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #4eaa32;
                }

                .signinfacebook{
                    background: url('../img/assets/facebook-signin.png') no-repeat 19px 11px, url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #2e56aa;
                    padding: 13px 51px !important;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    font-weight: bold;

                }
                    .signinfacebook:hover{
                     background: url('../img/assets/facebook-signin.png') no-repeat 19px 11px, url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #284e9e;
                    }

                .signintwitter{
                    background: url('../img/assets/facebook-signin.png') no-repeat 19px 11px, url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #78cdf0;
                    padding: 13px 51px !important;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    font-weight: bold;

                }
                    .signintwitter:hover{
                     background: url('../img/assets/facebook-signin.png') no-repeat 19px 11px, url('../img/assets/btn-mist.png') repeat-x 0 50% #59b6dc ;
                    }

        #nav{
          margin: 1px 0px 0 0px;
          color: #777;
          padding:0px;
          float:right;
        }
          #nav>li{
            float: right;
            font-size: 1.25em;
            line-height: 1;
          }
            #nav>li>a{
              display: block;
              height: 50px;
              line-height: 50px;
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #999;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
              #nav>li>a:hover{
                color: white;
              }
              #nav>li#user-profile{
                  float: right;
                  padding: 0px;
                  margin-left: 30px;
                  width: 51px;
                  margin-top: 0px;
              }
              #nav>li img{
                float: right;
                position: relative;
                top:14px;

              }
                #nav li ul.nav-tabs{
                  width: 180px;
                  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
                  background: #333;
                  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
                  border-radius: 6px;
                  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
                  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;
                  border-top-left-radius: 0;
                  border-top-right-radius: 0;
                  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
                  -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
                  background-clip: padding-box;
                  z-index: 999;
                  position: absolute;
                  right: 0px;
                  display:none;
                }

                  #nav li ul.nav-tabs li a{
                    display: block;
                    padding: 5px 15px;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    line-height: 2;
                    color: #999;
                    background: none;
                    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                    -moz-box-shadow: none;
                    box-shadow: none;
                  }

                    #nav li ul.nav-tabs li a:hover{
                      color: #ddd;
                      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
                      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
                      -moz-border-radius: 0;
                      border-radius: 0;
                    }
                    #nav li ul.nav-tabs li{
                      clear: left;
                      margin: 0;
                      width: 100%;
                    }

                    #nav li#user-profile ul.nav-user-profile li:first-child a{
                      font-weight: bold;
                    }
                    #toggle-nav{
                      display: none;
                      }
                      #nav li#user-profile span.profile-name{
                        display: none;
                      }

                      #notify-btn-desktop{
                          background: url(../img/assets/notify.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
                          text-indent: -99999px;
                          display: inline-block;
                          height: 21px !important;
                          width: 31px;
                      }
                        #notify-btn-desktop:hover{
                          background: url(../img/assets/notify.png) 0 -22px  no-repeat;
                        }
                      #message-btn-desktop{
                          background: url(../img/assets/message-icon-nav.png) no-repeat;
                          text-indent: -99999px;
                          display: inline-block;
                          height: 21px !important;
                          width: 31px;
                          margin-left:23px;
                      }
                         #message-btn-desktop:hover{
                            background: url(../img/assets/message-icon-nav.png) 0 -27px  no-repeat;
                         }

                     @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

                         #header-icons{
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 14px;
                            right: 20px;
                      }
                       }

                      #notify-btn-phone{
                        display: none;
                      }
                      .discover-tabs{
                        font-size: 14px;
                        padding-bottom: 4px;
                        float: left;
                      }
                      .discover-tabs li{
                        float: left;
                        padding-right: 40px;
                      }
                       .discover-tabs li a{
                        color: #777;
                        font-weight: normal;
                       }
                       .discover-tabs li a:hover{
                        color: #a6a6a6;
                       }

                      .discover-tabs .active{
                        font-weight:bold;
                        color: #444;
                      }
                      .line-break{
                        clear: both;
                        padding-top: 18px;
                        border-bottom: 2px solid  #ddd;
                      }
                      .line-break.profile{
                        padding-top: 10px;
                        border-bottom: 2px solid  #ddd;
                      }

                      .discover-tabs.right{
                        float: right;
                        font-size: 12px;
                        margin-top: 17px
                          }
                      .discover-tabs.right li{
                        padding-right: 15px;
                      }
                      .discover-tabs.right .last{
                        padding-right: 0px;
                      }
                      #charts-link{
                        margin-left: 40px;
                        margin-right: 140px;
                        }

/* =============================================================================
  NAVIGATION MEDIA MAX 800PX
   ========================================================================== */
                    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){

                    #header{
                        position: fixed;
                        height: 40px;
                    }
                      #notify-btn-phone{
                        display: block;
                      }

                    #toggle-nav{
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0px;
                        display: block;
                        width: 48px;
                        height: 40px;
                        text-indent: -9999px;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        background-position: 15px 50%;
                        background:red;
                        opacity: .5;
                      }

                        #logo a{
                          display: block;
                          height: 40px;
                          margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
                        }

                          #logo{
                            float: none;
                            padding-right: 0;
                            text-align: left;
                          }
                            #nav{
                              float: left;
                              width: 100%;
                              margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                              text-align: left;
                              display: none;
                              background: #323232;
                            }
                            #nav li{
                              position: relative;
                              float: none;
                              margin-right: 0;
                              text-align: left;
                              font-size: 12px;
                              background: #323232;
                            }
                            #nav li:hover{
                              background: #2e2e2e;
                            }

                            #nav li ul.nav-tabs{
                              display: block;
                              position: static;
                              float: none;
                              width: 100%;
                              left: 0;
                              margin: 0;
                              padding: 0;
                              background: none;
                              -webkit-border-radius: 0;
                              -moz-border-radius: 0;
                              border-radius: 0;
                              -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                              -moz-box-shadow: none;
                              box-shadow: none;
                            }
                            #nav li ul.nav-tabs li a{
                              padding: 15px;
                              font-size: 12px;
                              font-weight: normal;
                              line-height: 1;
                              text-transform: none;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile{
                              float: none;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile{
                              float: none;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile img{
                              float: left;
                              margin: 0 8px 0 0;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile span.profile-name{
                              display: inline-block;
                            }
                            #nav li a:hover{
                              -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                              -moz-box-shadow: none;
                              box-shadow: none;
                              color: #fff;
                              background: #2e2e2e;
                            }
                            #nav li ul.nav-tabs li a:hover{
                              color: #999;
                              background: none;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile ul.nav-tabs li:first-child{
                              display: none;
                            }
                            #header-inner{
                                width: auto;
                                padding: 0;
                            }
                            #nav li a{
                              height: auto;
                              padding: 15px;
                              font-size: 14px;
                              font-weight: bold;
                              line-height: 1;
                              border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
                              color: #fff;
                              background: #323232;
                            }
                            #nav>li img{
                              top:0px;
                            }

                            #wrap-inner{
                              padding-top: 60px;

                            }

                            #nav li#user-profile #search{
                              margin-top: 0;
                            }
                            #nav li#user-profile{
                                position: relative;
                                top: auto;
                                right: auto;
                                padding: 0px;
                                margin: 0px;
                                width: 100%;
                            }
                            input.search-text{
                              width: 96%;
                              padding-top: 16px;
                              padding-bottom: 16px;
                              -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                              -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                              box-sizing: border-box;
                              background: url(../img/assets/chart-sprite.png) 17px -161px no-repeat white;
                              font-size: 13px;
                              padding: 16px 5px 16px 44px;
                              margin-left: 12px;
                              margin-bottom: 10px;
                            }
                            #upload-responsive{
                              display: block !important;
                            }
                            #upload-green-btn{
                              display: none;
                            }

                    }

                    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
                     .discover-tabs.right{
                      float: left;
                     }
                    }
                    @media screen and (max-width: 580px){
                     .discover-tabs li{
                      float: none;
                      line-height: 24px;
                     }
                     }

                     .tools, .tools a{
                      color: #aaa;
                     }
                     .tools{
                      margin: 0 auto !important;
                      text-align: center !important;
                      margin-top: 10px;
                      width: 200px;
                     }


                      #upload-container .display-box ul.tools li{
                        float: left ;
                        display: block;
                        clear: none;
                        margin: 0px;
                        padding: 0px;
                        width: auto;
                      }
                        #upload-container .display-box ul.tools .views{
                        background: url(../img/assets/chart-sprite.png) 0 -71px no-repeat;
                        height: 20px;
                        width: 30px;
                        padding-left: 24px;
                        margin-top: 4px;
                        float: right;
                        }
                        #upload-container .display-box ul.tools .share-this{
                        background: url(../img/assets/chart-sprite.png) 0 -102px no-repeat;
                          height: 20px;
                          width: 24px;
                          float: left;
                        }
                        #upload-container .display-box ul.tools .comments{
                          background: url(../img/assets/chart-sprite.png) 0 -38px no-repeat;
                          height: 20px;
                          width: 30px;
                          padding-left: 20px;
                          margin-left: 13px;
                          margin-top: 4px;
                            float: right;
                        }
                        #upload-container .display-box ul.tools .cheeky-kisses{
                            background: url(../img/assets/social-grey.png) 0 -39px no-repeat;
                            height: 20px;
                            width: 30px;
                            padding-left: 20px;
                            margin-left: 15px;
                            margin-top: 8px;
                            font-size: 11px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }
                          #upload-container .display-box ul.tools .ditches{
                            background: url(../img/assets/social-grey.png) 0 0px no-repeat;
                            height: 20px;
                            width: 30px;
                            padding-left: 20px;
                            margin-top: 4px;
                            margin-top: 8px;
                            font-size: 11px;
                            font-weight: bold;
                        }
                        #upload-container .user-info{
                          font-size:12px;
                          color: #aaa;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/d6Cc8/6/

```
.toggleMenu {
display: none;
background: #ed1b2f;
padding: 10px 0;
color: #000;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: send me a screenshot of what is the final thing you are looking at

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you need to write js in these way.

```
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('html');

 function resize() {

    if ($window.width() < 480) {


  $("#toggle-nav").click(function () {
       $("#nav").slideToggle('slow');
   });

    //  

    }else{
 $("#nav").slideUp();// if its not worked write your code   
  }

}

$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');

});
```